# Bash comparison check to accept values only with format 0.1

Tags: regex, bash, integer, version-numbering

I have this snippet:

```
if [[ $1 =~ ^[+-]?[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*$ ]]; then
     echo 'version is good'
     exit 0
else 
     exit 1
fi
```

The problem is that, the snippet `$1 =~ ^[+-]?[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*$` should only validate versions formatted as `number.number`

Currently this chunk of code validates inputs as

```
1
01
0.1
```

Is there any way of making the code to only accept inputs formatted as `0.1 / 0.3.2 / 0.1.141` etc.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

To clarify this question, the code should only accept numbers separated with dots, like software program versioning.

Comment: To be clear, do you want to only accept inputs with at least 2 groups of numbers separated by `.`? And are we accepting `+` and `-` signs in the input? That part of the regex seems irrelevant to this question.

Comment: You write "_should only validate versions formatted as `number.number`_" and then "_Is there any way of making the code to only accept inputs formatted as `0.1` / `0.3.2` / `0.1.141` etc._" This is contradictory. Please edit your question and clarify your specification. No comments, no images, no external links, just edit your question. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @RenaudPacalet @rchome sorry for my typos, what I would like to achieve is just to validate inputs passed as ``number.number.number`` It should only accept numbers separated between dots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest this regex: `^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+){1,2}$`

Answer (score 0):

I propose without regex :

```
[[ "0" == ?([+-])+([0-9]).+([0-9.]) ]] && echo OK # Nothing 
[[ "01" == ?([+-])+([0-9]).+([0-9.]) ]] && echo OK # Nothing 
[[ "0.1" == ?([+-])+([0-9]).+([0-9.]) ]] && echo OK # OK 
[[ "0.3.2" == ?([+-])+([0-9]).+([0-9.]) ]] && echo OK # OK 
[[ "0.1.141" == ?([+-])+([0-9]).+([0-9.]) ]] && echo OK # OK
[[ "10.1.141" == ?([+-])+([0-9]).+([0-9.]) ]] && echo OK # OK
```

> To clarify this question, the code should only accept numbers
> separated with dots, like software program versioning.

```
[[ "0" == +([0-9]).+([0-9.]) ]] && echo OK # Nothing 
[[ "01" == +([0-9]).+([0-9.]) ]] && echo OK # Nothing 
[[ "0.1" == +([0-9]).+([0-9.]) ]] && echo OK # OK 
[[ "0.3.2" == +([0-9]).+([0-9.]) ]] && echo OK # OK 
[[ "0.1.141" == +([0-9]).+([0-9.]) ]] && echo OK # OK
[[ "10.1.141" == +([0-9]).+([0-9.]) ]] && echo OK # OK
```